# Сделать приватность для профиля Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть Flask приложение, в котором есть есть страницы профиля

```py
@app.route("/user/<int:user_id>")
@login_required
def profile(user_id):
    ...
```

на этой странице выводиться личная информация пользователя, но проблема заключается в том, что любой пользователь может заменить id в адресной строке и перейти на чужой профиль, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать доступ к профилю только для владельца

Comment: Логично, что проверяйте совпадение user_id и id текущего залогиненного пользователя

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как получить id залогиненного пользователя?

Comment: Не могу знать, это зависит от того, как вы в принципе сделали залогинивание (если вообще сделали)